# Primefaces ListDataModel and SelectableDataModel

Tags: primefaces, datatable

I am trying to override getRowData and getRowKey methods which is written in http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/datatableRowSelectionRadioCheckbox.jsf.

but i cannot implement it gives an error "The method getRowKey(InputMain) of type ProjectBean must override or implement a supertype method".

I am using datatable with checkboxes just like the example in the page of primefaces.

I searched google for codes of the SelectableDataModel and ListDataModel but i could not find.

If anyone can help me I would be appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the argument type accepted by `getRowKey` exactly matches the template type for the SelectableDataModel.

So, assuming each row of your table is of type `InputMain`, then your class definition should look like this:

```
    public class InputDataModel extends ListDataModel<InputMain> implements
        SelectableDataModel<InputMain> {
```

and your `getRowKey` lines should look like this:

```
    @Override  
    public Object getRowKey(InputMain inputMain) {
```

You should also be creating a separate class for your `DataModel`. It should not be a bean.